# Copyright for logo

Tags: logo, copyright

I made a logo for a company, in the logo I used a vector inspired by a vector stored on a site that sells vectors / images.
In other words, I built a new vector based on the seen there. The vector is used as the main object but are different colors plus a few shapes and  words.
There is a possibility have problems with copyright?
Mention that the vector is quite common, nothing special.

(sorry for my English)

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't answer this for you. Maybe you could have a look on Google at what are the limits of copyrighted elements, or ask/browse the http://law.stackexchange.com/. Any answer you'll get here will be useless to you without showing what symbol you mean, the logo you created, the name, where it's going to be used, etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because only a lawyer can answer this and without seeing artwork, even designer's can't offer valid *opinions*. And options from *designers* would ultimately not be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a possibility that you may have problems with the copyright. It would depend on the nature of the particular art, what you mean by 'inspired by', your country's laws regarding intellectual property protection, as well as other factors.

The biggest issue, however, is that it sounds like you're using a very common symbol as a logo. That, alone, may mean it's not easily copyrightable.

Comment: Using a common symbol as a logo might not be much use as a logo, either.